# Creating a Camera View similar to Instagram, Path, or Photovine

Tags: uiview, path, camera, instagram

I haven't worked with the iPhone's camera much.

I've done basic apps using UIImagePickerViewController but that only shows the basic camera functions.

What are apps like Instagram, Path, or Photovine using to make the cooler layout with more options?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are essentially using a cameraOverlayView over the UIIImagePicker.

[You can read about it here.](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/UIImagePickerController/UIImagePickerController.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIImagePickerController/cameraOverlayView)

[And get an apples sample code here.](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/PhotoPicker/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010196) http://goo.gl/RPwtD